# Nested labels or how to specify when to display a part of a label

Tags: html, angularjs

Suppose I have a label with this text:

```
<label>This is a text. This is another text.</label>
```

How can I specifiy that the second sentence shall only be displayed when a boolean is true. Like this:

```
<label This is a text.</label> 
<label ng-hide="myctrl.showSecondText">This is another text</label>
```

I want to display the second phrase in the same line if the value for ng-hide is true.

Answer (score 0):

You may get second phrase inside span tag
for example and add ng-hide on it.

Comment: It's not being displayed in the same line but beneath: `<label This is a text.</label><span ng-hide="myctrl.showSecondText">
<label>This is another text</label></span>`

Comment: @YourReflection but you may use: 
<label>First phrase. <span ng-hide="condition">Second phrase.</span> </label>

Answer (score 0):

Use **`ng-show`**

```
 <label ng-show="ctrl.showSecondText">This is another text</label>
```

```js
var myapp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myapp.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.showSecondText = true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as ctrl">
 <label>This is a text.</label>
 <label ng-show="ctrl.showSecondText">This is another text</label>
</body>
```